# npm is not installing the packages with npm i vite command

Tags: tailwind-css, package.json, npm-package

i am trying to install vite using command "npm i vite" in the VS code Terminal but i am getting error

"
npm ERR! code ERR_INVALID_URL
npm ERR! Invalid URL

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-07-24T18_23_31_393Z-debug-0.log  "[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiDo8.png)

i tried different commands like

npm --version
npm install -g npm  (this command also gave me  the same error )
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
npm install -g yarn (giving the same error)

i am attaching the image of my npm config list[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHW4s.png)